# How to query Stack Exchange in LINQPad?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange, data-explorer

I recently recalled seeing my classmate querying Stack Exchange data using [LINQPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad) (many years ago). When I tried to figure out a way to do this I found an old blog post, *[Using LINQPad to Query Stack Overflow](http://coderjournal.com/2010/06/using-linqpad-to-query-stack-overflow/)*, but when I tried to follow the steps I could not connect to an [OData endpoint](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom) which is depreciated based on [Jeff's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/).

Is there still a way to query Stack Exchange data using LINQPad or has that functionality been completely replaced by https://data.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: The OData endpoint is likely unavailable because the URL rewriting isn't working, but I'm not sure whether or not that's intentional.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows 2012 R2 server group SEDE was recently moved to did not have the HTTP Activation for WCF services available, causing a 404.  It has just been enabled and OData is up and running again.

Apologies for the oversight - this is the only software we run that needs anything WCF, so it doesn't get a lot of attention.  We'll take a look at adding it to the template for the server tier SEDE runs on in all data centers.

Comment: I love WCF but it's always a PITA to deploy.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I agree with at least the "always a PITA" part of that ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to query now.